# search last occurrence of string in less

Tags: less

What's the best way to search for the last occurrence of a string in `less`?

`?string` works for small files but doesn't seem to work with large or non-trivial syntax-highlighted files (eg, `cat /var/log/cron | ccze -A | less -r`), I had to go to the end of the file with <kbd>G</kbd> first then do a reverse search from there.

Comment: I think that's the way to do it in `less`.

Answer (score 5):

<s>You can search a string like always with `/string` but then just press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to get the last occurrence.</s>

Edit:

You can reverse search with <kbd>N</kbd> after typing your search `/string`.

Less only loads the visible part of the file and a little before and after it, so its remains quick for larger files but only searches in the part that is loaded.

If you want to search over the whole file you should use vim as editor or grep/sed/awk on the commandline.

Thanks @sudodus for pointing out my false answer.

Comment: This brings me to the end of the file in less 487-0.1

Comment: Yea you don't always necessarily open an actual file in `less`, it could have been piped eg `cat /var/log/cron | ccze -A | less -r` (added to the question now). <kbd>N</kbd> didn't find do a reverse search after `/string`, neither does <kbd>?</kbd> (<kbd>?</kbd> just after `/string` does a reverse search of `string`, difference being <kbd>N</kbd> does a search in the *opposite* direction).

Comment: I do want to page through the text so didn't want to use grep/sed/awk. Vim doesn't feel right and not sure if it can work with text piped from stdout, however I did try it with a log file eg `vim -R /var/log/cron` and yes reverse search is instant with syntax highlighting. That may do for most cases having said that in the spirit of the question which is about `less`, can it load the whole file like vim?

Comment: @sunnz, You can use the option `-bn or --buffers=n` that specifies  the  amount of buffer space `less` will use for each file, in units of kilobytes (1024 bytes). See `man less`. So it depends on the size of the file and the size of your RAM (how much is available), if you can load the whole file. (It would not be nice to start swapping.)

Comment: @sudodus I have tried that option like so: `cat /var/log/cron | ccze -A | less -r -b-1` but it still requires me to <kbd>G</kbd> first, just doing a reverse search (ie `?string`) straight away still doesn't work.

Comment: @sunnz, Yes, according to `man less` that is how it works, `?pattern    Search backward in the file for the N-th line containing the pattern. The search starts  at the last line displayed`, but it should find the last page and the last occurence faster, when the whole fine is in RAM.